# Using node-html-pdf with FileSaver.js

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, electron

I'm using this module in my Electron app to convert some database data into HTML string and then convert it to a PDF file. But I want to show the user a 'save as' dialog instead of saving it to a specific folder. I couldn't find a way to do that using filesaver.js. Can any body help me with this?

I tried this using electron dialog api but it didn't work.

```
dialog.showSaveDialog(function(filename) {
    if (fileName === undefined) return;
    pdf.create(html).toStream(function(err, stream) {
        stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('file.pdf'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found an answer for my question by a help from 'marcbachmann'

here is my code :

```
dialog.showSaveDialog({
      filters: [{ name: 'PDFs', extensions: ['pdf']}],
                    title: 'Save the Report as PDF',
                    defaultPath: path.join(app.getPath('desktop'), 'title1'+'.pdf')}
       , function(filename) {

       pdf.create(docx).toFile(filename,function(err, res){
              console.log(res.filename);
       });

   });
```